# Differential Equation Problem Book Recommendations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

Looking for college level Differential Equation book with loads of difficult problems. Something like GN Berman. I am looking for difficulty like something irodov or Morin is to Physics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Book For Differential Equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757007/best-book-for-differential-equations)

Comment: @Shreyas Sinha: You might want to review the books here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232143/large-list-of-ordinary-differential-equations-for-practice

Comment: Maybe **A Book of Problems in Ordinary Differential Equations** by Krasnov/Kiselyov/Makarenko [translation of 1978 3rd Russian edition, MIR Publishers, 1981, 332 pages]. This book has a lot of worked examples, 967 problems for the reader (about 95% have answers on pp. 293-326). I wasn't able to find a copy online (only searched briefly, mostly at archive.org). For some reason I have 2 identical hardback print (essentially new) copies of the 1983 2nd printing -- I used to order by postal mail MIR books back in the early-mid 1980s, and I must have accidentally ordered a copy of this book twice.

Comment: @Moo: I didn't see your comment until I finished writing/posting my previous comment, but interestingly I notice that at the MSE question you cited I described the same Krasnov/Kiselyov/Makarenko book. It also appears that I overstated there when I said all the problems have answers. There are a few (my guess is about 5% of the problems) that do not have answers.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: No problem! Amazing how hard it is to find that wonderful book!

Comment: @Moo: I suppose I tried looking for a copy online when I wrote the other comment several years ago, but when I was writing my first comment here I tried searching for the book and couldn't find it. I originally mentioned how I was surprised at not finding it since so many MIR books are at archive.org and because I have 2 print copies of it (thus I would guess that it is probably not an especially rare or valuable book), but I exceeded the maximum comment character length, so I left that part out in my first comment here.